# how to get information like email-id of currently logged in user using Federated authentication in a win azure app

Tags: azure, federated-identity, azure-appfabric

A windows azure application accept Federated authentication where user can log in using any of the gmail , facebook and live id . Once user is logged in , how can one extract information like getting user name and email id specifically . ?

Answer (score 2):

The email address is presented as a claim from the identity provider.

If you're using MVC (for example) an easy way to read the email address is to add some properties to your controller like this:

```
public ClaimsPrincipal ClaimsPrincipal
{
    get
    {
        return this.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
    }
}

public ClaimsIdentity ClaimsIdentity
{
    get
    {
        return this.ClaimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    }
}

public string UserEmailAddress
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var claim in this.ClaimsIdentity.Claims)
        {
            if (claim.ClaimType == @"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress")
            {
                return claim.Value;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, Live ID will not give you the email address, or the user's name.

Comment: Live Id give me the user name but not email id . I want to have it to interact with logged in user i.e. sending mails and notification .I think many websites/apps have live id login and they  send notification mails on the same id from which user has logged in ... so how they do it ...

Comment: They probably ask the user for their email address.

Comment: Hmm. This happen sometime . but then there is not point of supporting live login , if user is again asked for email is after login .

Comment: I suggest you use Yahoo! and Google then.